# Dash Extendable Graph -- use extendData without Interval

Tags: python, websocket, callback, plotly, plotly-dash

I haven't seen this question asked in the exact same way online, so I'm gonna try to ask this in first principles (at least as far as Dash first principles go)

I have a websocket feed streaming data from the internet. I'll get data from it, and sometimes I'll use that data to update my plot with a new data point.

I am trying to use the `@app.callback(Output('graph', 'extendData')]` approach to do so.

### What I've Tried:

I'm starting off with the code [from this Github repo](https://github.com/bcliang/dash-extendable-graph). The same code is also pasted below:

```
import dash_extendable_graph as deg
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import random

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app.css.config.serve_locally = True

app.layout = html.Div([
    deg.ExtendableGraph(
        id='extendablegraph_example',
        figure=dict(
            data=[{'x': [0],
                   'y': [0],
                   'mode':'lines+markers'
                   }],
        )
    ),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval_extendablegraph_update',
        interval=1000,
        n_intervals=0,
        max_intervals=-1),
    html.Div(id='output')
])


@app.callback(Output('extendablegraph_example', 'extendData'),
              [Input('interval_extendablegraph_update', 'n_intervals')],
              [State('extendablegraph_example', 'figure')])
def update_extendData(n_intervals, existing):
    x_new = existing['data'][0]['x'][-1] + 1
    y_new = random.random()
    return [dict(x=[x_new], y=[y_new])], [0], 100


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The code above just adds a new random point to the graph every 1 second. It uses the interval object to do so.

I'm trying to combine it with my callback function from my websocket code, which parses and prints a message in a callback method. Shown below, simplified:

```
def websocket_callback(msg):
    # 
    # 
    # do some message parsing...
    # (for now let's just assume casting to int is all that's needed)
    # 

    new_point = int(msg)
    print(f"Just received: {new_point}")

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(url, on_message=websocket_callback)
wst = threading.Thread(target=ws.run_forever)
wst.daemon = True
wst.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1) # Wait for infinite websocket read
```

What I tried to do is just slap the decorator on top of the `websocket_callback` method as so:

```
counter = 0

@app.callback(Output('extendablegraph_example', 'extendData'),
              [Input('interval_extendablegraph_update', 'n_intervals')],
              [State('extendablegraph_example', 'figure')])
def update_extendData(n_intervals, existing, msg):
    # 
    # 
    # do some message parsing...
    # (for now let's just assume casting to int is all that's needed)
    # 
    global counter
    counter +=1
    new_point = int(msg)
    return [dict(x=[counter], y=[new_point])], [0], 100
```

The problem with that is that the function is now being called by the websocket feed *and* the `Interval` object from the example.

This code doesn't work for a lot of reasons, and I got stuck here

---

#### Solution?

Is there a way to manually trigger an `extendData` event without needing the callback? I'm looking for a way to separate both parts, the websocket parsing part and the graph refresh/update part. Something like:

```
@app.callback(Output('graph', 'extendData'))
def update_graph(new_x, new_y):
    return [dict(x=[new_x], y=[new_y])], [0], 1000


counter = 0
def websocket_callback(msg):
    # 
    # 
    # do some message parsing...
    # (for now let's just assume casting to int is all that's needed)
    # 
    global counter
    new_point = int(msg)
    update_graph(counter, new_point)
    counter +=1
```

that way I parse my message in `websocket_callback` and trigger a refresh of the graph manually.

Is there a way to do this? Running the code above (adapted to my setup) complains with the following error message:

````
dash.exceptions.CallbackException: Inputs do not match callback definition```

which I'm assuming is because that `app.callback` decorator doesn't understand the two x,y inputs.

So I'm so lost...
````

Comment: `update_graph(counter, new_point)` doesn't seem to have inputs. Callbacks must have at least one input and one output. I've done a small test and it's possible to call a callback like you're trying to do without it giving an error. That said, the code inside the callback is executed but won't result in a layout update. I've googled "plotly dash callback websocket" and found [this](https://www.dash-extensions.com/components/websocket). Not a direct answer to your question, but I think you could make it work with the dash extensions `WebSocket` component I linked.

Comment: The second example listed at the link seems pretty similar to what you're trying to do. I'd try to change that to work with extendData.